# How to make a server reply after receiving a request/data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, networkstream

I'm trying to set up a connection between a client program and a server program.
Sending data from the client to the server works fine, but I have no clue how I can send back a reply immediately from the server to the client.
For example in this case I have a program for a hotel to store all reservations (server) and a clientprogram for where people can look up their reservations. The clientprogram sends the ID of the client to the server and needs to send a serialized Hashtable of that client's reservations back.

My client code looks like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

const int POORT = 4001;
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, POORT));

using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket)) {
     using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns)) {
           sw.WriteLine(klantId);
           sw.Flush();                 
     }
}

socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
```

My server code:

```
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 4001);

Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,                               ProtocolType.Tcp);
serverSocket.Bind(ep);
serverSocket.Listen(50);

try {
     string klantid;
     while (true) {
          using (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept()) {
              using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(clientSocket)) {
                  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns)) {
                      klantid = sr.ReadLine();

                      // Searches the reservations
                      Hashtable reservaties = hotel.ReservatiesZoeken(int.Parse(klantid));

                      // Tried this to send the data. Doesn't seem to work.
                      using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                          BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                             formatter.Serialize(stream, reservaties);
                             stream.Flush();
                          }
                      }
                  }
               }
          }
    }
    finally {
         serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
         serverSocket.Close();
    }
```

I guess I could implement a listener in the client and make a new connection from the server to the client, but I couldn't help but feeling that it should be possible to send the reply over the same connection as the request.

Comment: Do you REALLY need to go that low-level? Can't you use some kind of service-framework, e.g. WCF or WebAPI, which does all that stuff for you?

Comment: Sadly I have to since it's a project for school to practice making a connection between server and client...
It's explained a little in our textbooks, but not nearly enough and I can't seem to find any clear examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the socket on the client right after you sent the ID. You need to keep it open and wait for the server to send it's data, e.g.:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, ...);

// open and send ID

int dataAvailable = 0;
while (dataAvailable == 0 || dataAvailable != socket.Available)
{
    dataAvailable = socket.Available;
    Thread.Sleep(100); // if no new data after 100ms assume transmission finished
}

var data = new byte[dataAvailable];
socket.Receive(data);

socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
```

*DISCLAIMER:* This is not "production ready code" and should just give you a hint how you could solve your problem. Espceially the "wait 100ms" part should NOT be used in production code...

Comment: 'Thread.Sleep(100); // if no new data after 100ms assume transmission finished' - ugh, terribru.

Comment: @MartinJames: Yes, but VERY simple ;-). Feel free to suggest a better way - I am always interessted in how others do such stuff. In "real code" I would probably send the length of data as the first few bytes to know how much data will be sent, but for this example this simple solution should work just fine...